# Error en Update: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, sql-server-2017

Estoy obteniendo un error al intentar actualizar un registro en mi base de datos SQLServer, desde NetBeans.
Este es el error: String or binary data would be truncated

Mi Tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado(
idEmpleado int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
apellido varchar(50) NOT NULL,
cedula varchar(20) NOT NULL,
estadoCivil char(1) NOT NULL,
genero char(1) NOT NULL,
edad int NOT NULL)
```

Clase de actualizacion:

```
public String modificarEmpleado(Connection con, Empleado emp) throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    String sql = "UPDATE EMPLEADO SET nombre = ?, apellido = ?, cedula = ?, estadoCivil = ?, genero = ?, edad = ? "
            + "WHERE idEmpleado = ?";

    try {
        /*pst recibe la conexion y preapara la SQL*/
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, emp.getNombre());
        pst.setString(2, emp.getApellido());
        pst.setString(3, emp.getCedula());
        pst.setString(4, emp.getEstadoCivil()+"");
        pst.setString(5, emp.getApellido()+"");
        pst.setInt(6, emp.getEdad());
        pst.setInt(7,emp.getIdEmpleado());
        mensaje="REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO!!!!!";
        pst.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        pst.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        con.rollback();
       /*Mensaje de SQL*/ 
        mensaje="No se pudo actualizar el mensaje \n"  + e.getMessage();
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Metodo de actualizacion:

```
public void modificar() throws SQLException{
    emp.setIdEmpleado(7);
    emp.setNombre("Pepito");
    emp.setApellido("Perez");
    emp.setCedula("Al251014");
    emp.setEstadoCivil('S');
    emp.setGenero('M');
    emp.setEdad(15);
    mensaje = ebo.modificarEmpleado(emp);
    System.out.println(mensaje);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
    Test test = new Test();
    /*test.insertar();*/
    test.modificar();
}
```

Cual pudiese ser el error?

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que te estás olvidando de poner el género en el prepared statement, en la posición 5 estas pasando el apellido en lugar del género, que es una string de más de un carácter y por lo tanto tienes ese error.

Comment: Peor que una novatada, muchas gracias.
Prestare mas atención a la próxima.
Saludos

@Alex